# jQuery :input selector in Chrome Extension's Content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to do this in Content script

```
console.log('Found ' + $(':input').length + 'inputs');
```

And I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': ':input' is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because you don't seem to have jQuery available in your content script. However in Chrome developer console, [`$`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#selecting-elements) is built-in symbol shortcut for `document.querySelector` method.

So when you run `$(':input')` it is equivalent to `document.querySelector(':input')` which of course throws above exception, because `:input` is not a valid CSS selector.

Comment: I see, but jQuery is there.

Comment: I'm getting the same for `jQuery(':input')`

Comment: What is `console.log( jQuery.fn.jquery )`?

Comment: `2.1.1 -deprecated,-dimensions,-effects,-effects/Tween,-effects/animatedSelector,-event-alias,-offset,-css/hiddenVisibleSelectors,-wrap`